# Primary Key which exists Multiple Times

Tags: sql, sql-server, primary-key

I want to create a Table "News" as Example. In this Table I have a `group_id` and a `lang_id`. The `group_id` stays as for the ID for the "News" but as `group_id` because it has a Translation in some Languages. This `group_id` shall be `autoIncrement` if I insert a new "News" with different `lang_id` but the same for every `lang_id` I attach to the Insert Command.
For Example a Table what I want to Achieve.
I say here new News in German(1),English(2),French(3) it shall Create new Rows for this Langs with the same `group_id` but itself auto Increment.

**Table:** `News`

```
x-----------------------------x
| group_id|  lang_id  | news  | 
x---------|-----------|-------x            
|    1    |     1     | Hallo | 
|    1    |     2     | Hello |
|    1    |     3     | Holla |
|    2    |     1     | bye   | 
|    2    |     2     | byebye|
|    2    |     3     | Ciao  |
x-----------------------------x
```

How could I achieve that with an Primary Key, `group_id` would be the Primary Key??

Comment: You can't because it's not unique. Primary keys must be unique. You should create a key using both groupid and lang_id. Primary key means that if you ask for a row with a specific key you get back one and only one row.

Comment: PS you can't set `group_id` as autoincrement because you'll get a *different* value for each row.

Comment: group_id, lang_id combination would form the primary key and you could make group_id an "auto inc" value by using a sequence. Better yet make it 2 tables where that group_id is in 'parent' table.

Comment: If you have two ids like this in a table, then you should have reference tables for each id.

Comment: So its quite not Possible/BestPractice? Then I think I will go with a Reference Table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary key must be unique by definition.
This means that in your case, the primary key of the table should be the combination of `group_id` and `lang_id`.
As to the question if your group_id can be an identity column, That's possible, but you will have to use `SET IDENTITY_INSERT` for every new language for an existing content.

example:

```
CREATE TABLE tblNews 
(
    group_id int identity(1,1) not null,
    lang_id int not null,
    news varchar(20),
    primary key(group_id, lang_id)
)

INSERT INTO tblNews VALUES(1, 'hello')

SET IDENTITY_INSERT tblNews ON
INSERT INTO tblNews (group_id, lang_id, news) VALUES(1, 2, 'hello')
INSERT INTO tblNews (group_id, lang_id, news) VALUES(1, 3, 'holla')
SET IDENTITY_INSERT tblNews OFF

INSERT INTO tblNews VALUES(1, 'good bye')

SET IDENTITY_INSERT tblNews ON
INSERT INTO tblNews (group_id, lang_id, news) VALUES(2, 2, 'byebye')
INSERT INTO tblNews (group_id, lang_id, news) VALUES(2, 3, 'Ciao')
SET IDENTITY_INSERT tblNews OFF

SELECT *
FROM tblNews
```

results:

```
group_id    lang_id     news
1           1           hello
1           2           hello
1           3           holla
2           1           good bye
2           2           byebye
2           3           Ciao
```

Though this design is clearly possible, I'm having a hard time recommending it. I would probably use a different approach for a multilingual database - one table for the news, one table for the languages, and one table for the translations:

```
tblNews 
newsId int identity(1,1) primary key,
-- and whatever else content that is not language-dependent

tblLanguages
languageId int identity(1,1),
languageName nvarchar

tblNewsContent
NewsId (pk)
LanguageId (pk)
Contant nvarchar
```

Comment: I will mark it as Correct Answer for as best Solution for such Problem. I will go with the 3 Table Schema as it is the Best Practice.

Comment: Glad to help :-). I don't know if this is the best practice, but it is the best one I know of :-).

Answer (score 0):

The three table method is the best option, but I would say it needs something unique that isn't dependent on the translation.

If you are on sql server 2012+ you can use a sequence for this situation, though I can't say it is the best practice.

rextester: http://rextester.com/RRTJ4439

```
create sequence dbo.NewsIdSequence as int start with 1 increment by 1;

create table Lang (
    id int not null
  , name nvarchar(64)
  , alias nvarchar(64)
  , constraint pk_Lang primary key clustered (id)
  , constraint uq_Lang_Name unique (name)
  );

create table NewsLanguage (
    news_id int not null 
     constraint df_NewsLanguage_news_id default (next value for dbo.NewsIdSequence)
  , lang_id int not null
  , title   nvarchar(256) not null
  , article nvarchar(max) not null
  , constraint pk_NewsLanguage primary key clustered (news_id, lang_id)
  , constraint fk_langLanguage_lang_id foreign key (lang_id) references lang(id)
  );

insert into Lang (id, Name, alias)
  select top 3 langid, name, alias 
    from syslanguages 
    order by langid;

declare @NextNewsId int;
set @NextNewsId = next value for dbo.NewsIdSequence;

insert into NewsLanguage( news_id, lang_id, title, article) 
            select @NextNewsId, 0, 'Hello', 'Hello ... ' 
  union all select @NextNewsId, 1, 'Hallo', 'Hallo ... '
  union all select @NextNewsId, 2, 'Bonjour',  'Bonjour ...';

set @NextNewsId = next value for dbo.NewsIdSequence;

insert into NewsLanguage( news_id, lang_id, title, article) values
    (@NextNewsId, 0, 'Goodbye','Goodbye ...' )
  , (@NextNewsId, 1, 'Auf Wiedersehen', 'Auf Wiedersehen ...' )
  , (@NextNewsId, 2, 'Au Revoir', 'Au Revoir ...');

select * 
  from dbo.NewsLanguage nl 
    inner join dbo.Lang l on nl.lang_id = l.id
```

The three table method would be better, as Zohar Peled explained. Here's a version without hungarian notation:

```
create table Lang (
    id    int not null identity (1,1)
  , name  nvarchar(64)
  , alias nvarchar(64)
  , constraint pk_Lang primary key clustered (id)
  , constraint uq_Lang_Name unique (name)
  );

create table News (
    id int not null identity (1,1)
  , unique_column_of_importance  nvarchar(64)
  , constraint pk_News primary key clustered (id)
  , constraint uq_News_Title unique (unique_column_of_importance)
  );

create table NewsLanguage (
    news_id int not null
  , lang_id int not null
  , title   nvarchar(256) not null
  , article nvarchar(max) not null
  , constraint pk_NewsLanguage primary key clustered (news_id, lang_id)
  , constraint fk_NewsLanguage_news_id foreign key (news_id) references news(id)
  , constraint fk_NewsLanguage_lang_id foreign key (lang_id) references lang(id)
  );
```